# Loading hidden DIV's in JQUERY Masonry

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry

I have used JQuery Masonry in following formt:
First I build my content in lets say a for loop, like this:

```
for (var d = 0; d< contentFourSpace; d++)
  {
     box = document.createElement('div'),
     text = document.createTextNode( cFour[d] );   
     box.className = 'contentfour box col first' ;

     box.className = 'contentfour box col' ;
     box.appendChild( text );
     MainContent.push(box);
  }
```

Then I hand it over to masonry to render it on page, something like this:

```
$container.prepend( MainContent ).masonry( 'reload' );
```

That works fine.

I wonder is the following possible.
Lets say I have HTML page with normal content. Within that page I have certain number of DIV's that have some content in them. All of those DIV's are hidden.
How can I load those hidden DIV's in Masonry?
In other words, those DIV's will be sitting on the page always hidden, how can I send to Masonry for display?

There might be a way where I scan the DIV's and copy them, but that would be much overhead, since I will end up with copies... or I also might cut/copy... but this is not good solution, since I would need to keep track of all the DIV's around.

Comment: Let's say they all have a class of "brick", couldn't you simply use jQuery to show them? `$(".brick").show();`  Appending them to another div will remove them from the original, no need to copy.